# Getting Error in converting json Data into jsonobject

Tags: android

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.ahsan.ethlon2, PID: 11641 java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: ""
>
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
>
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
>
> at
>   com.example.ahsan.ethlon2.MegaMenu$GetContacts.onPostExecute(MegaMenu.java:363)
>
> at
>   com.example.ahsan.ethlon2.MegaMenu$GetContacts.onPostExecute(MegaMenu.java:281)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>
> at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>
> at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Comment: this is the API I am using 
https://digitalcodeeye.com/ethlon/api/get-parent-categories

Comment: Please also post your code. Please see : [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: { HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
String url = SERVER_URL+get_parent_categories;
jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url); Log.e("TAG", "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
return null;}
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { super.onPostExecute(result);
if (jsonStr != null) {
JSONArray contacts;
try { contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(jsonStr));
String id = c.getString("id"); String image = c.getString("image"); String name = c.getString("name");}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an empty string (`""`) into a number. Add a check to the string before converting it to a number.

```
if(!string.isEmpty()) {
    Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```